# How to read/show an ArrayObject in Angular project?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am receiving the following data from an API:

```
[[9, "Brown", 2], [1, "Amy", 1]]
```

I want to show it in a table format in my Angular app. I have tried the following code, but I think it's not the right way to do it.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of report">
        <td>{{user[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{user[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{user[2]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `<tr *ngFor="let user of report; let i = index">
    <td>{{ user[i] }}</td>
  </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

It is array of array to you need to iterate two for loop in you case like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let user of data">
             <td *ngFor="let e of user">{{ e }}</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```